# RS-232 Device Echoing All Serial Writes in PySerial

Tags: python, serialization, pyserial

My Python 2.7 program is using pySerial to communicate with a RS232/RS485 device ([manual here, page 40](http://www.lesker.com/newweb/gauges/pdf/manuals/375usermanual.pdf)).

**Problem:** However it appears that everything that is written to the serial port is being echoed back as the response to `serial.readline` after timing out. Why is this?

**print serial:**

```
Serial<id=0x1006e4350, open=True>(port='/dev/tty.usbserial-AL01MZAQ', baudrate=19200, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=3, xonxoff=False)
```

For example, if I write to serial

```
#01RD\n
```

I get the response

```
#01RD\n
```

instead of

```
*01_7.60E+02\n
```

Changing the baud rate in pySerial but not on the device also causes the echoing on timing out after writing. Shouldnt having a non-matching baud rate causes gibberish to be returned?

Answer (score 1):

If your sending a string use a carriage return, not newline.
You might have to use a carriage return to wake up the device before sending the command. Then strip out the extra characters on the print out statement.

Run `cmd_send(x)`:

```
x = '#01RD'
def cmd_send(x):    
    try:
        ser.write(x +'\r')
        out = ''
        sleep(.1)
        while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
            out += ser.read(1)
        if out != '':
            print out
        else:
            print "nothing"
    except Exception, e:
        print "serial error: " + str(e)
```